# Django query: FOR EACH month AND name SUM values

Tags: django, orm

What I need: for each month, I need to get the total sales (SUM) from John and Mary. There are other people in the database, but I only need info from both of them.

```
[
  ["19-Nov", "John", 511.97], ["19-Nov", "Mary", 0], 
  ["19-Dec", "John", 568.21], ["19-Dec", "Mary", 1542.08], 
  ["20-Jan", "John", 621.20], ["20-Jan", "Mary", 401.06], 
  ["20-Feb", "John", 621.39], ["20-Feb", "Mary", 0], 
  ["20-Mar", "John", 0], ["20-Mar", "Mary", 871.14], 
  ["20-Apr", "John", 604.25], ["20-Apr", "Mary", 653.34], 
  ["20-May", "John", 584.94], ["20-May", "Mary", 1218.43],
]
```

The date must be formatted in this "Year-Month" type in order (oldest to newest ones). The total sales, even if it's zero, must be printed.

My Django model:

```
class Sellers(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

Is it possible to create just one Django query to retrieve data in this format?

Tks!

Comment: are you using Postgres?

Comment: No, I'm using SQLite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this should work.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField,Sum

Sellers.objects.filter(
    name__in=['Jhon','Mary']
).annotate(
    formatted_date=Func(
         F('date'),
        Value('YY-Mon'),
        function='to_char',
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).values(  
     'name','formatted_date'
).annotate(
    sales_sum=Sum('value')
).order_by('formatted_date')
```

The Postgre 'to_char' function may need to be changed to fit your DB.

Comment: I'm using SQLite (standart Django db). I got an error using your code: "no such function: to_char" - probably because the database. Got any idea?

Comment: May be the strftime function should work for you. You need to change the code to formatted_date=Func(
         Value('%Y-%m'),F('date'),
        function='strftime',
        output_field=CharField()
    ). I don't remember well but I thing SQLite has no format go get the month by name.

Comment: Pretty nice! It worked! Let me ask 02 final questions: a) in any month, if name is not found, the correct is to print this info anyway for Mary or Jhon (e.g.: `{'name': 'Jhon', 'formatted_date': '2020-08', 'sales_sum': 0}`. The last thing is: I'd like to SUM 'John' and 'Paul' results in a month. In this way, both 'Jhon' and 'Paul' sales must be added inside Jhon's dict, e.g.: `{'name': 'John', 'formatted_date': '2020-08', 'sales_sum': #John and Paul combined}`. Can you help me again?

Comment: For your second case you can do this: `Sellers.objects.filter(name__in=['Jhon','Mary','Paul']).annotate(seller_name=Case(When(name='Jhon',then=Value('Jhon')),When(name='Paul',then=Value('Jhon')),default=Value('Mary'),output_field=CharField()),formatted_date=Func(Value('%Y-%m'),F('date'), function='strftime', output_field=CharField())).values('seller_name','formatted_date').annotate(sales_sum=Sum('value')).order_by('formatted_date')`

Comment: Perfect!! The only thing missing is: if name (Jhon or Mary) is not found for any month, the correct is to print this info anyway (e.g.: `{'name': 'Jhon', 'formatted_date': '2020-08', 'sales_sum': 0}`)

Comment: Unless that this data is on the DB  this query can't be performed. Since you can't now for what month need to set a sales_sum = 0.

Comment: Edu, you said that date must be on the DB, otherwise the query can't be performed for every month. But, is there a way to provide a fixed started date until the current day? In this way, we wouldn't use the DB date value but a fixed date. The started date would always be, for example, 11-01-2019 and the query would go on until now.